# Firebase Scheduled Function has not deployed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

Following exactly this [Firebase Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#deploy_a_scheduled_function) I can't see my function deployed. I want to trigger the function at a specific time, for test purposes I am increasing a few minutes from the deployment time. I have activated the required GCP Services as: App Engine App and PubSub.

*functions* directory tree:

```
$ tree functions -L 1
functions
├── firestore-debug.log
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── schedule-monthly.js
└── ui-debug.log
```

*schedule-monthly.js*

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

//firebase deploy --only "functions:schedule-monthly" // functions:fileName


exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("30 8 * * *")
    .timeZone("America/Sao_Paulo")
    .onRun(() => {
        console.log("Triggering email")
        return null;
    });
```

Deploy: `$firebase deploy --only "functions:schedule-monthly"`

```
=== Deploying to '****'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint ****/functions
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
⚠  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
⚠  functions: You are using an old version of firebase-functions SDK (3.15.4). Please update firebase-functions SDK to >=3.20.0
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /****/functions (37.65 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!
```

Checking the deployments:

```
$firebase functions:list

┌───────────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ Function                              │ Version │ Trigger                                              │ Location    │ Memory │ Runtime  │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ create_transaction                    │ v1      │ https                                                │ us-central1 │ 256    │ python39 │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ ext-firestore-send-email-processQueue │ v1      │ providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write  │ us-central1 │ 256    │ nodejs14 │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ hello_http                            │ v1      │ https                                                │ us-central1 │ 256    │ python39 │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ listenReserveCreated                  │ v1      │ providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create │ us-central1 │ 256    │ nodejs10 │
```

No scheduled functions on the console as well.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it was deployed in the right project?

Comment: Just double checked, the project is correct.

Comment: Facing same error. Found any solution?